# Animate TextSwitcher, ViewFlipper or ViewSwitcher with children of different heights

Tags: android, android-animation, viewflipper, viewswitcher, android-viewflipper

I want to use a TextSwitcher (or some other switcher with TextViews inside) to animate changing Text.
It should have a sliding animation to slide the old text out to the left and the new one in from the right.

My problem is that when a long text gets replaced by a short text, the TextSwitcher changes its height to a smaller view and the view that is moving out of the screen changes its height too. I want the animated view that is moving out of the screen to **keep its height until its gone**. Only the new Text should have the new height.

I have

> android:measureAllChildren="false"

enabled because my TextView is centered vertically.

I have tried using TextSwitcher, ViewSwitcher and ViewFlipper, but all of these changed the height of the text that was sliding out.